# Flutter GoRouter is not navigating when it's wrapped in a service class

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-go-router

I have this router service.

```
class AppRouter {
  late final AppService appService;
  GoRouter get router => _goRouter;
  AppRouter(this.appService);

  late final GoRouter _goRouter = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: appService,
    initialLocation: APPPAGE.home.toPath,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: APPPAGE.home.toPath,
        name: APPPAGE.home.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const NavScreen(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: APPPAGE.splash.toPath,
            name: APPPAGE.splash.toName,
            builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: APPPAGE.onBoarding.toPath,
            name: APPPAGE.onBoarding.toName,
            builder: (context, state) => const IntroScreen(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: APPPAGE.error.toPath,
            name: APPPAGE.error.toName,
            builder: (context, state) =>
                ErrorScreen(error: state.extra.toString()),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: APPPAGE.deepLink.toPath,
            name: APPPAGE.deepLink.toName,
            builder: (context, state) {
              String url = state.pathParameters['url']!;
              String source = state.pathParameters['source']!;
              return WebViewScreen(
                deepLink: true,
                link: 'https://example.com/$source/$url',
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) =>
        ErrorScreen(error: state.error.toString()),
    redirect: (context, state) {
      // final loginLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.login.toName);
      final homeLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.home.toName);
      final splashLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.splash.toName);
      final onboardLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.onBoarding.toName);

      // final isLogedIn = appService.loginState;
      final isInitialized = appService.initialized;
      final isOnboarded = appService.onboarding;

      // final isGoingToLogin = state.location == loginLocation;
      final isGoingToInit = state.location == splashLocation;
      final isGoingToOnboard = state.location == onboardLocation;

      // If not Initialized and not going to Initialized redirect to Splash
      if (!isInitialized && !isGoingToInit) {
        return splashLocation;
        // If not onboard and not going to onboard redirect to OnBoarding
      } else if (isInitialized && !isOnboarded && !isGoingToOnboard) {
        return onboardLocation;


        // If not logged in and not going to login redirect to Login
      } else if ((isInitialized && isGoingToInit) ||
          (isOnboarded && isGoingToOnboard)) {
        return homeLocation;
      } else {
        // Else Don't do anything
        return null;
      }
    },
  );
}
```

of course the routes list is bigger than that, and everything is working as expected even the deeplinks.
The issue starts when I'm tapping on a notification, in the logs it's showing that it's pushing to the route, which it means it's triggered but it's not navigating.

> pushing
> /post/layngrany-sdr-daoay-dakhstny-bayzkhany-sod-o-drkrdny-bayzy-oatk-l-bghda-dkn

And that's the code when the tap on the notification is triggered:

```
static void _navigateToeRoute(RemoteMessage event) async {
    final AppRouter appRouter = locator<AppRouter>();

    appRouter.router.pushNamed(
          APPPAGE.deepLink.toName,
          pathParameters: <String, String>{
            'source': 'firstParameter',
            'url': 'secondParameter',
          },
        );

  }
```

I did a lot of debugging, What I found out is when I remove the AppRoute wrapper around the GoRoute like below the navigation starts working again but that way I'm loosing the state and I'm not able to have access to the AppService and the redirections broke;

```
final GoRouter goRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: APPPAGE.home.toPath,
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: APPPAGE.home.toPath,
      name: APPPAGE.home.toName,
      builder: (context, state) => const NavScreen(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: APPPAGE.splash.toPath,
          name: APPPAGE.splash.toName,
          builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: APPPAGE.onBoarding.toPath,
          name: APPPAGE.onBoarding.toName,
          builder: (context, state) => const IntroScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: APPPAGE.error.toPath,
          name: APPPAGE.error.toName,
          builder: (context, state) =>
              ErrorScreen(error: state.extra.toString()),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: APPPAGE.deepLink.toPath,
          name: APPPAGE.deepLink.toName,
          builder: (context, state) {
            String url = state.pathParameters['url']!;
            String source = state.pathParameters['source']!;
            return WebViewScreen(
              deepLink: true,
              link: 'https://example.com/$source/$url',
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
  errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorScreen(error: state.error.toString()),
  // redirect: (context, state) {
  //   // final loginLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.login.toName);
  //   final homeLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.home.toName);
  //   final splashLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.splash.toName);
  //   final onboardLocation = state.namedLocation(APPPAGE.onBoarding.toName);

  //   // final isLogedIn = appService.loginState;
  //   final isInitialized = appService.initialized;
  //   final isOnboarded = appService.onboarding;

  //   // final isGoingToLogin = state.location == loginLocation;
  //   final isGoingToInit = state.location == splashLocation;
  //   final isGoingToOnboard = state.location == onboardLocation;

  //   // If not Initialized and not going to Initialized redirect to Splash
  //   if (!isInitialized && !isGoingToInit) {
  //     return splashLocation;
  //     // If not onboard and not going to onboard redirect to OnBoarding
  //   } else if (isInitialized && !isOnboarded && !isGoingToOnboard) {
  //     return onboardLocation;

  //     // in future use this link to understand how to add a condition if you want
  //     // to have a condition based on loggedIn or no
  //     // https://github.com/ishangavidusha/flutter-go-router-example/blob/master/lib/router/app_router.dart

  //     // If not logedin and not going to login redirect to Login
  //   } else if ((isInitialized && isGoingToInit) ||
  //       (isOnboarded && isGoingToOnboard)) {
  //     return homeLocation;
  //   } else {
  //     // Else Don't do anything
  //     return null;
  //   }
  // },
);
```

and from the notifications service I call it as a global variable

```
static void _navigateToeRoute(RemoteMessage event) async {

    goRouter.pushNamed(
      APPPAGE.deepLink.toName,
      pathParameters: <String, String>{
        'source': 'firstParameter',
        'url': 'secondParameter',
      },
    );
}
```

So the only way for this to work is to make the GoRouter as a global variable, and I thought maybe the issue is with the AppService and removed that too still inside the AppRouter class, but didn't navigate too. the problem looks like when the GoRouter is inside the AppRouter it doesn't have enough power to push it to the next route.